# Different header for the list of acronym and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr, glossaries

I use *fancyhdr* to tune the headers and footers of my thesis. But I have problems went it arrives in the *List of Acronyms* and *Bibliography* sections. I do not know how to change it for each section. Currently I am doing that:

```latex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO]{PhD thesis}
\fancyhead[LE]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

%############################################################################

...

\include{chapter/...}

...

%############################################################################

%\newcommand{\glossaryname}{List of Acronyms}
\fancyhead[LE]{\glossaryname}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms, toctitle=List of Acronyms]


\fancyhead[LE]{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio/...}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\appendix
\fancyhead[LE]{Appendix\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
\include{appendix/...}
```

But I get the `\bibname` title (Bibliography) for both, the list of acronyms and bibliography sections. I tried to move the `fancyhead` command after the `\printglossary` and `\bibliography`, but in that case, it is the `\glossaryname` that is displayed.

How to change the header for each section?

Comment: Try putting a `\clearpage` before each `\fancyhead`. In general you should make sure that each change in the headers or footers is executed when it is certain that the previous page has already been output.

Comment: Thanks. It works!